# Quadratic congruences modulo composite $n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I know how to solve quadratic congruences modulo $p$ a prime. I also know how to solve quadratic congruences modulo $n$ by breaking $n$ down into various combinations of prime factors and working out the solutions in each of the congruences. However, this method I find to be very tedious.

Let $Q(x) = x^2 -1$. I simply wish to find the least value of $x > 0$ such that
$$Q(x) \equiv 0 \bmod 51$$ $$Q(x) > 0$$
Is there an efficient method to find $x$? I do not wish to find all the values of $x$, just the least positive value that satisfies this congruence and the inequality.

Comment: Have you tried using the Chinese remainder theorem?

Comment: @JanKubica considering 51 = 17*3, I took different congruences taking combinations of prime factors of 51 to yield solutions x = 1,16,35,50. But I am asking for some efficient method especially when there are a large number of prime factors. Also finding all these solutions isn't very useful for my purpose.

Comment: Are you asking for an approach specific to $x^2-1$, or are you asking for an approach applicable to an arbitrary quadratic polynomial with integer coefficients (and simply using $x^2-1$ as an example)? When you say "efficient," what do you have in mind? If you know the solutions modulo a prime $p$, then Hensel's lemma provides a systematic approach for determining the solutions modulo $p^d$ for any $d\in\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: The Chinese remainder theorem gives a description of the solutions modulo a positive integer $n$ in terms of the solutions modulo the prime-power factors of $n$. Solving the systems appearing in the description amounts to computing some modular inverses, which can be done effectively (in the objective sense of algorithmic complexity) using the extended Euclidean algorithm. In what way(s) is this standard approach unsuitable for your purpose?

Answer (score 1):

It's, easier than you think, simply factor out $x^2-1=(x+1)(x-1)$, then, you factor out 51 and you consider all factors bigger than $\sqrt{51}$, the smallest two factors that have a difference of two, you take x= the bigger one of them -1
If you don't find that, you get x=51-1 which is in fact the smallest solution for such a problem

Comment: Should it not be x=16?